# Angular $route service doesn't get injected to a controller on time - getting undefined initially, on page load, but then all works like a charm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

Every time I refresh the page, I am getting multiple of the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'activeSite' of undefined
```

Six of them per page reload - apparently two errors per each tab.
After that the site works properly, with no errors.
My original project was generated with yeoman and it was working just fine with no errors, until the error appeared seemingly out of nowhere. 
I was able recreate the problem with this Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fT3heMEgxfT9zLPKObC9?p=preview
On the first glance all looks good, but check out the console and you'll see what I mean.
Thank you for your time.
Jared

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
if ($route.hasOwnProperty('current')) {
    return (active === $route.current.$$route.activeSite);
}
```

?

Comment: Reaching for the .hasOwnProperty when it's not necessary just doesn't feel right. Also the $$route is not needed for your solution to work. Nevertheless it works, so +1.

Comment: I'm sorry, wrote in haste. I promise to pay attention to it =)

Answer (score 1):

During the page rendering, `$route.current` could have no `activeSite` property. You can to this to avoid the error

```
$scope.site = function (active) {
    if ($route.current !== undefined) {
        return (active === $route.current.activeSite);
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: This works, but isn't there an 'angular' way to prevent this error? Maybe I could refactor my code somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Since your bindings are defined outside the ng-view, AngularJS may evaluate your binding before the ng-view gets set, i.e while loading the view form remote location and hence this error.

Comment: What do you mean by 'bindings are defined outside the ng-view'?

Comment: The tab bindings defined like `ng-class="{active: site('first-site')}"` can get evaluated even before the current route is set.

Comment: Is there a way to defer the evaluation to after the current route is set?

Comment: Better to check for null, as provided in other answers.